# How to simulate 2-finger tap with keyboard modifier?

Tags: google-chrome, trackpad, magic-trackpad

Chrome has introduced [a new feature requiring a weird 2-finger tap gesture](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=403619#c115) on a particular button. It's an awkward gesture and difficult to time it right.

Is there any way to make ctrl-tap act as if two fingers had been pressed on the trackpad? Or some other solution that would avoid the need to use 2-finger tap for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) is a great app that can help you with this.

You can install this by going into their website and download or by installing it with `homebrew cask` [here](http://macappstore.org/bettertouchtool/)

Now just for an example, I've posted an image of something you could do with it
[image: better touch tool]

Comment: Good tool - thanks. Only downside is it doesn't support ctrl-click anywhere. The gesture dropdown requires a specific position like top-left. So the best choice was just to use a corner with no modifier (ie no ctrl, just tap the corner).